# How to approach repeated subject trials in spss?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, t-test, repeated-measures

Im having this problem not sure how to approach it to make a valid analysis. I have 3 groups of joints in three different conditions. The first was intact and the other 2 were with reconstructed ligaments. I measured 5 loading cycles for each subject (5 repeated measurements), and i want to check differences between treatment groups (intact and the two reconstructed). Is the between-groups output of a mixed anova in spss a valid analysis or should i be using t-test for each couple of groups? Im not sure how to treat the 5 measurements for each subject correctly. Im getting a non significant difference between groups in mixed anova although the groups have quite the numerical gap.